# APIS for ask user location in the broswer (No with window.navigator)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know if there is any free or paid non-Google API that gives you the position of the user from browser, to work with mapbox gl and React

I already know window.navigator with getCurrentPosition method, and get the geolocation

```
const successCallback = (position) => {
  console.log(position);
};

const errorCallback = (error) => {
  console.log(error);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: So what is the issue with getCurrentPosition?

Answer (score 1):

You do have a few options. 
One as you already know and cited before, the native window api.

There is also a google service as you inquired.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview 
Follow the link and read the documentation, very comprehensive.

Amazon Service 
https://aws.amazon.com/pm/location/

And IP Geolocators which are less accurate. 
Here is a service https://ipgeolocation.io/

Comment: thanks let me try

Answer (score -1):

The most common way to access someone's location (with permission) is using the Permissions API

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API

Comment: I know, but I want to use other API for country problems